`AnimationMixer.uncacheAction` causes exception
I'm making a webb animation with ThreeJS. I'm creating copies of an object and having them traverse down the screen. One object is created every second. When an object reaches the bottom, an event listener removes the object.
The problem is that when an animation is removed from the mixer, the mixer still tries to play it on update. When it's time to remove an object, four have been created. One animation is removed from the mixer, but it still counts to four animations during the update, and tries to call update on an undefined value.
If I replace window.setInterval with window.setTimeout, only one object is created. It is removed correctly without further updates, making me think there's some sort of race condition. This is the javascript code:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';

const
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(),
    clock = new THREE.Clock();

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(1920, 1080);
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1920 / 1080, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 40;

new RGBELoader().load("brown_photostudio_02_4k.hdr", texture => {
    texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
    scene.environment = texture;
    scene.environmentRotation = new THREE.Euler(0, 0, 1.05);
});

let model;

new GLTFLoader().load(
    "model.glb",
    function (gltf) {
        model = gltf.scene.children[0];
    },
    undefined,
    function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    window.setInterval(addModel, 1000);
});

function addModel() {
    const obj = model.clone();

    scene.add(obj);
    const
        x = Math.random() * 40 - 20,
        y = Math.random() * 2 + 10,
        z = Math.random() * 40 - 20,
        track = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack(".position", [0, 4], [x, y, z, x, y - 24, z]),
        clip = new THREE.AnimationClip("clip", -1, [track]),
        action = mixer.clipAction(clip, obj);
    action.loop = THREE.LoopOnce;
    action.play();
}

mixer.addEventListener('finished', e => {
    mixer.uncacheAction(e.action.getClip(), e.action.getRoot());
});

function animate() {
    mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

